# VueJS - How can i refresh a table component from another component?

Tags: vue.js

I have two Vue components: one is a form and another is a table, they are in the same page. I want to refresh the table with new values when the form is submitted.

In order to do this, i need to call the function that fetches data and shows it on the table from the form component, so i need to call a function across two different components, which i did and it works.

The problem is that while i can call the function in the other component from the form component, the table doesn't refresh with new values, how can i fix this?

Here is my code:

the form component:

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios'

    export default {

      props:{

        order:{
          type:String, 
          default:'data'
        },

      },

      mounted() {
          console.log('Component mounted.')
      },

      data() {
          return {
            name: '',
            description: '',
            output: ''
          };
      },
      methods: {
          formSubmit(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              console.log('Called fetchData!')
              let currentObj = this;
              axios.post('MYURL', {
                'add_data': data, 

              })
              .then(function (response) {
                  this.fetchData()
                  currentObj.output = response.data;
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                  currentObj.output = error;
              });
          }

          fetchData: function(){
           this.$root.$emit('table_component')
          },
      }
    }

</script>
```

The table component:

```
<template>

  <v-data-table 
    :headers="headers"
    :items="customers"
    :items-per-page="5"
    :hide-default-footer="true"
    class="elevation-1"
  >

  </v-data-table>
</v-container>
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios';

export default {
 
  data() {
    return {

      search: '',

      headers: [
        { text: 'Name', value: 'Name' },
        { text: 'Item', value: 'Item' },
      ],

        customers: [],
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.fetchData()

    this.$root.$on('table_component', () => {
            this.fetchData()
    },

  },

  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      fetch('MYURL')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data)
          this.customers = data;
        })
    },

  }
}

</script>
```

Here is what i'm doing in this code: when the form is submitted and the response is received, i call the function `fetchData()`. The function is called because i see the `console.log('Called fetchData!')` being fired, so that works, the only thing that doesn't work is that the table doesn't refresh with new values. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have a problem with your context in the then function

```
formSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Called fetchData!')
  let currentObj = this;
  axios.post('MYURL', {
    'add_data': data, 
  })
    .then((response) => {
      this.fetchData()
      currentObj.output = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      currentObj.output = error;
    });
}
```

You can either use an arrow function as shown above to call this.fetchData

Or you can use bind

```
formSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Called fetchData!')
  let currentObj = this;
  axios.post('MYURL', {
    'add_data': data, 
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      this.fetchData()
      currentObj.output = response.data;
    }.bind(this))
    .catch(function (error) {
      currentObj.output = error;
    });
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you a lot! What does bind do? How did it solve my problem? This was very helpful!

Comment: the content of function () {...} has it's own "context". Therefore you cannot access your outer contexts "this" anymore - as the "this" within your function simply refers to something different. By using .bind(this) on the function you set the functions context to the current context and ensure that this is the same in both.
When using arrow functions () => {...} it is done automatically :)